# Unable to pass prop into dict in react

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, gatsby, react-props

I am trying to change the colour of a div in react by using a dict.

```
import * as React from 'react'

import {
    container
} from './zoneButton.module.css'

const ZoneButton = ({ colour }) => {

    const colourPrimaryDict = {
        'pink': 'var(--pastel-pink-primary)'
    }
    const colourSecondaryDict = {
        'pink': 'var(--pastel-pink-secondary)'
    }

    return (
        <div className={container} style={{
            backgroundColor: colourPrimaryDict[{ colour }],
            color: colourSecondaryDict[{ colour }]
        }}>
            { colour }
        </div>
    )
}

export default ZoneButton
```

When I enter 'pink' into the dict the colour of the div changes however when i try and pass through the { colour } prop that is given the string 'pink' the dict dose not return the requested colour.

```
<ZoneButton colour={'pink'}/>
```

If this is a bad way of doing things, is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for dynamically trying to an object property is slightly off:

```
import * as React from 'react'

import {
    container
} from './zoneButton.module.css'

const ZoneButton = ({ colour }) => {

    const colourPrimaryDict = {
        'pink': 'var(--pastel-pink-primary)'
    }
    const colourSecondaryDict = {
        'pink': 'var(--pastel-pink-secondary)'
    }

    return (
        <div className={container} style={{
            backgroundColor: colourPrimaryDict[colour],
            color: colourSecondaryDict[colour]
        }}>
            { colour }
        </div>
    )
}

export default ZoneButton
```

Hopefully that helps!